# Add class to another page attribute using URL id - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have attached id with URL. Ex: When I click `Link 1`, it has `#tab-2` id and it takes me to landing page. In landing page I have find which element has `#tab-2` id then i have to add class `.active`.

I tried but no luck. Please any one correct my code. Thanks

**[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gscyoa0j/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/gscyoa0j/1/#tab-2">LINK 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/gscyoa0j/1/#tab-44">LINK 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/gscyoa0j/1/#tab-74">LINK 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Landing Page**

```
<div class="tab">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="tab-2" class="active" >LINK 1 Content</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab-44" >LINK 2 Content</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab-74" >LINK 3 Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu ul li a").each(function(){
              var url = window.location.pathname;
              var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              var land = $('.tab').find("id");
              if( land == id ) {
                $('this').addClass('active');
              }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your requirement, you can retrieve the hash value from the URL of the page using `window.location.hash`. You can then use that to directly select the required element and add a class to it on load of the new page:

```
$(function() {
    var id = window.location.hash; // = '#tab-2', in your first link.
    $(id).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i do it for `href="tab-2"`.

Comment: Those links would never work as the `/tab-2` URL does not exist. You would have to have the leading `#`.

Comment: Sorry. I mean in landing page I have `<a href="#tab-2" >LINK 1 Content</a>` link like this. This code will work `$("a[href$=hash]").addClass('active');`   ?

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. Can u please tel me below code is correct or wrong.!
`var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('a[href="'+hash+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var hash = window.location.hash;
     $(hash).addClass('active');
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$('this').addClass('active');` by `$(this).addClass('active');`

```
if( land == id ) {
   $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault` it prevents the default action and Use `window.location.hash` to getting the hash element in the url

```
$(".menu ul li a").click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var url = window.location.hash;
          $(".tab ul li a").removeClass('active');
          $(url).addClass('active');

})
```